# Horizontal sidebar beside canvas

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to write a web application. In essence, the entire webpage should be filled with a canvas on the left, and a sidebar on the right. This is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Qubit Simulator</title>
    <style>
        body{
            margin:0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 0px;
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: auto;
        }

        #sidebar{
            height:100%;
            width:30%;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:0px;
            background: #00FFFF;
        }
    </style>
</head>


<body>
<canvas id="canvas">
    Sorry, this example cannot be run because your browser does not support the &lt;canvas&gt; element
</canvas>
<div id="sidebar"></div>
...
</body>
</html>
```

This is what shows up:

[image]

Apparently, the sidebar doesn't come out at all. What's worse, the canvas does not fill up 100% of the vertical space, despite the explicit instruction in the code to do so.

This is my first time doing HTML/CSS, so I'm experiencing a huge paradigm shift (from .NET GUI and Android programming). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please also provide critique for any other part of the code should you find it weird. Thanks!

Comment: Could you reproduce it in a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<style>
    body{
        margin:0px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    canvas {
        height: 100%;
        width: 80%;
        margin: 0px;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: auto;
        float:left;
        background: #000;
    }

    #sidebar{
        height:100%;
        width:30%;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:0px;
        background: #00FFFF;            
    }
</style>
```

what i added is float:left to the canvas.
The height of the sidebar and canvas is tricky, but ill look into it. You want it to go all the way down?

Comment: Yes, it should supposedly fill up the empty space below.

Answer (score 0):

A few problems I see:

`<canvas id="canvas">` - not sure what this is. Shouldn't it be `<div id="canvas">` and then closed in a `</div>`

Also, in your CSS you missed the # that needs to be in front of 'canvas'.

Also, if you want your canvas on the left, and sidebar on the right, add `float:left;` to the canvas and `float:right;` to the sidebar in your CSS.

Comment: You are a genius. I knew something had to be wrong with <canvas id="canvas">. However, I tried using float:left; and float:right; together with width:70% and width:30% respectively. The gap below is still there, and the sidebar is still missing. Upon using the "inspect element" function in chrome, it turns out that the width of the sidebar is 0px.

Comment: Try adding display:inline; to both canvas and sidebar in your CSS

Comment: Also, put some content in between your <div> tags for the sidebar in your html.. This may be why nothing is showing

Comment: You are right. I added a button and the cyan colored background comes out now. However, the sidebar appears to be only as tall as the button. The canvas still doesn't fill up the bottom of the window, however. I really appreciate your help!